# Websocket Error: Invalid HTTP upgrade", code: 404

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, websocket, aws-application-load-balancer, ingress-controller

We have deployed an ALB for our spingboot application which consists of both Rest and Websocket services hosted in EKS cluster. We have added health check, ssl redirect etc. annotations in the ingress.yaml file. The listener is HTTPS: 443 and the SSL certificate is from ACM.

When we hit the ALB endpoint, rest service is working fine but receiving the following error with the websocket service.

Websocket Optional(wss://xxx.xx.xx.com:443/xx/xx/xx/xx) disconnected with error Optional(Starscream.WSError(type: Starscream.ErrorType.upgradeError, message: "Invalid HTTP upgrade", code: 404))

Versions:
aws-load-balancer-controller: v2.3.0,
Kubernetes version: 1.19,
Platform version: eks.7.

Appreciate your inputs in resolving this issue.

Comment: 404 means the requested URL was not found. So either `wss://xxx.xx.xx.com:443/xx/xx/xx/xx` is wrong to begin with, or it is not active, or the like.

Comment: Thanks Remy! The same works with NLB but ALB is throwing this error. The rest service works fine and the issue is only with websocket service. What could be wrong with the ingress?